# textFieldDidEndEditing firing "too late"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a multiview process the user is entering in data and I'm saving it to the model class properties each step along the way.

I use `textFieldDidEndEditing` to check if the input is valid, and if so, saves the entered data.

On the view I have a continueButtonClicked event that checks to see if all the validations pass and if so loads the next view.  I do NOT set the properties of the model here, because I think I shouldn't have to since each field is saved to the model 1 field at a time.  However, I noticed some issues.

If the user is inside of a textbox and clicks the "Continue" button, the continueButtonClicked event fires BEFORE the `textFieldDidEndEditing`.  What ends up happening is that the next view is populated with the "old" model prior to the save happening in `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

What am I missing?  Is it proper to set all the properties on the Continue?  That's how I would do it if I were programming for the web, but it doesn't seem right for a native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this instead and see if that solves your problem?

```
textFieldShouldEndEditing:
```

Comment: Awesome!  This seems to have solved the issue.  I'm a little confused as to why textFieldShouldEndEditing fires twice though: once before the continueButtonClick for ALL fields, and a second time for active field after the continueButtonClick event fires.  It seems harmless, but just curious.

Comment: If it is the active one you really want, you can always determine that by testing if thats the first responder.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `resignFirstResponder` on the active textfield/textview (or on all of them), which will trigger the `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

In general, for such text editing issues, another approach is to abuse the `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:...` delegate method, in which you can determine the new value for every character entered. You should only revert to this method if there is no other way.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into this method as well when I get some time - just to wrap my head around it.  mbh's solution above just happened to be quicker for me to try, but I'm curious about this one as well